# MEAN making posts with individual url

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean

When I see questions on stackoverflow.com, I find https://stackoverflow.com/questions/**11234554**
that each post has individual url.

I have made a Q&A list that pulls data from mongoDB and an html page to have each question.
Do I create the URL based on the question number from database?
If so, how can I append /11234554 to /questions ?
I can make GET request to each item on the list, but what then?

```
router.get('/questions', function(req, res, next){

   "How do I make GET request to every question number?"        

})
```

Any guide will be appreciated!

Comment: This is done through simple url templating.  In MEAN, you would do this using express's app `param`. [here](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.param) is the express documentation.

Comment: Thanks. I now have /questions/:questionsId. I still got a question though. How do I use $routeprovider to get to the same question.html with different information?